# How do I initialize a 2D array of variable size in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a tic tac toe program and I need to create a 2D array of variable size in a class. This is how I have it written now:

```
class ticTacToe
{
     public:
         ticTacToe();
         void display();
         bool moveIsValid();
     private:
         int rows;
         int cols;
         int board[rows][col];
}
```

I have the board being read in from a file in the constructor but I am not sure how to make it of variable size so that I can read in a board of any size and then access it outside of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just a quick question though, when I use the array outside of the class do I just write ' ticTacToe newGame; ' ' newGame->board[i][j]; '

Comment: _do I just write  `ticTacToe newGame;`_ Yes, you don't use `new`.

Comment: Since 'board' is private variable, you can't access it outside of the ticTacToe class

Comment: @Quest You can give it an _accessor function_, what's the prob?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just answered his question above that he can't directly use it since it's private variable, but sure he can use accessors..

Comment: @Quest I didn't see their comment edit.

Answer (score 5):

> *"I have the board being read in from a file in the constructor but I am not sure how to make it of variable size so that I can read in a board of any size"*

In c++ you use a `std::vector` instead a raw array like follows

```
class ticTacToe {
     public:
         ticTacToe();
         void display();
         bool moveIsValid();
     private:
         int rows;
         int cols;
         std::vector<std::vector<int>> board; // <<<<
};
```

The *dynamic allocation* can be applied as follows in a constructor:

```
ticTacToe(int rows_, int cols_) : rows(rows_), cols(cols_) {
    board.resize(rows,std::vector<int>(cols));
}
```

> *and then access it outside of the class*

Well, I'm not sure that this is really a good idea, but you can simply add an accessor function for that member variable

```
 std::vector<std::vector<int>>& accBoard() { return board; }
```

The better design approach would be IMHO, to provide something like a separate function to read from a `std::istream`:

```
 void ticTacToe::readFromStream(std::istream& is) {
     // supposed the first two numbers in the file contain rows and cols
     is >> rows >> cols;
     board.resize(rows,std::vector<int>(cols));
     for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
         for(int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
             cin >> board[r][c];
         }
     }
 }
```

For real code you would check for input errors of course like

```
 if(!(is >> rows >> cols)) {
    // handle errors from input
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

In case this is homework and you cannot use the standard library:

```
// Declaration
int rows;
int columns;
int **board;

// Construction

board = new int*[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    board[i] = new int[columns];
}

// Destruction


for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    delete[] board[i];
}
delete[] board;
```

**Update:** You could perform a single allocation but it will be easier for you to work it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to have a dynamically sized array

```
int* board;
```

Then your constructor would be

```
ticTacToe::ticTacToe(int _rows, int _cols)
: rows{_rows}, cols{_cols}
{
    board = new int[rows * cols];
}
```

And your destructor

```
ticTacToe::~ticTacToe()
{
    delete[] board;
}
```

Or better yet use a `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> board;
```

Then your constructor would be

```
ticTacToe::ticTacToe(int _rows, int _cols)
: rows{_rows}, cols{_cols}
{
    board.resize(_rows * _cols);
}
```

Comment: You mean `vector<vector<int>>` insn't it ?

Comment: @Christophe Not necessarily. They could use a single vector and use row/column arithmetic. Up to them.

Comment: True, I think it would be easier/ better for the original poster to work with a one dimensional vector, though. Find its "square" and use row times height for values.

Comment: `index = (current_row * row_length) + current_column` example: the `index of [2][5] on a 5 by 5 board would be 25`.

Comment: @Cyber sure !  They could also write the programme directly in assembler :-D But if they'd work with a 2D board and have 2d alogrithm, why not use the language features that are intended for this purpose ?

Comment: @Christophe If you declare `int board[rows][col]` it looks like a 2D array, but in fact it *is already a 1D array*, that is what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use pointer to pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class ticTacToe{
private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **board; // POINTER TO POINTER
public:
    ticTacToe(int a,int b){
        rows=a;
        cols=b;
        board=new int*[rows];

        for (int k = 0; k < rows; ++k) {
            board[k]=new int[cols];
        }

        /*LET'S INITIALIZE CELL VALUES TO= 0*/
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                board[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    void display();
    bool moveIsValid();
};
```

Comment: The main problem of this problem is 2D array must be initialize dynamically.So we use pointers for initialize dynamically but using pointers is bit different when we have to initialize 2D array.Then we use pointer to pointer(int **board).It define with double asterisks mark which can hold pointer.after that we can assign pointer array to it (board=new int*[rows];).Then it can fill one dimension.To fill other dimension we can use loop and assign columns arrays to it.

Comment: Don't mention it as a comment, edit the answer and add the explanation.